# What is the correct way to open a form submit in a new window now target is deprecated

Tags: html, xhtml, forms

Normally I would us

```
<form target="_blank">
```

But looking through

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_form.asp

I notice the target attribute is deprecated.

So what is the correct XHTML compliant way to perform such an action?

UPDATE: Thanks, I appreciate that opening new windows is not generally a good idea but in this case it's a third party linking to our site who wants this effect and unfortunately whilst I can suggest good design to them whether they take my advice is another matter :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The target attribute is not deprecated (W3Schools is wrong again (and not the W3C)), it just doesn't appear in Strict.

If you want a new window from a form, then use the target attribute (and a Transitional doctype).

However, author triggered [new windows are considered harmful](http://diveintoaccessibility.org/day_16_not_opening_new_windows.html).